# Group Rows together based on Similar Text

Tags: python, text, dataframe, text-mining

I have a dataframe similar to this

```
Date    Amount  Narrative 
2017/01/12  50  Active356483
2017/01/12  30  Active798203
2017/01/15  70  1NB6893784
2017/01/23  80  Apple22222
2017/02/01  90  1NB6893784
2017/02/01  10  Apple3435
2017/02/02  10  Apple34532
2017/02/03  10  1NB7847573
2017/02/03  20  Apple78783783
2017/02/04  60  1NB6897383
2017/02/04  90  Apple893043
2017/02/04  100 Apple789302
```

I need to group rows that have a similar narrative. The Narrative column will tell you more about the originating company, however they also add a reference number. This reference does not mean anything to outside consumers. In the example above, an exact match on the Narrative column would not yield the desired result. I need all rows that are Active, 1NB and Apple to be grouped together. I can't simply strip the numbers because sometimes it does indicate account numbers. For example, a person will have Apple1-78872 and Apple2-674674. These should be considered as two different accounts.

```
Narrative   Date    Amount
Active798203    2017/01/12  50
        2017/02/12  30
1NB6897383  2017/01/15  70
        2017/02/01  90
        2017/03/01  10
        2017/04/01  60
Apple789302 2017/01/23  80
        2017/03/01  10
        2017/04/01  10
        2017/05/01  20
        2017/06/01  90
        2017/07/04  100
```

I was thinking of doing a text percentage match.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```